# Java 8 - Best way to read and store a file received in REST service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, file-upload

I want to have an application where user can upload a csv file in front-end (Angular). I want a rest service to read it and then store the file as a BLOB into Oracle database.

For the REST service, I will receive a MultipartFile object:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload")
public String processUploadFile(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) {
    // Call to a service 
}
```

For the entity, it will be something like this:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@Table(name = "FILE_UPLOAD")
public class FileUploadEntity implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "BLOB")
    @Lob
    private Blob blob;
    
    // ...
}
```

I saw that I have getInputStream() and getBytes() methods.

What is the best and optimized way to read the CSV file line by line to do a treatment and then to store it if the treatment is in success without error please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to process csv file, line by line, you could use any out of the following libraries:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
    <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

or

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-csv</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Let's imagine that your csv line represents some DTO object `YourDtoClass`. Example with usage of those libraries (make sure to customize according to your needs):

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv.CsvSchema;
import com.opencsv.CSVParserBuilder;
import com.opencsv.ICSVParser;
...

@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public void processUploadFile(@RequestParam MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
    // option #1. using `opencsv` library
    ICSVParser parser = new CSVParserBuilder()
            .withQuoteChar(ICSVParser.DEFAULT_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
            .build();
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getInputStream(), UTF_8));
    bufferedReader.lines()
            .forEach(line -> {
                // process line...
                log.info("line has been processed");
            });

    // option #2. using `jackson-dataformat-csv` library
    List<YourDtoClass> list = readCsv(YourDtoClass.class, file.getInputStream());
}

public <T> List<T> readCsv(Class<T> clazz, InputStream stream) throws IOException {
    CsvMapper mapper = new CsvMapper();
    CsvSchema schema = mapper.schemaFor(clazz)
            .withoutHeader()
            .withColumnSeparator(CsvSchema.DEFAULT_COLUMN_SEPARATOR)
            .withArrayElementSeparator(CsvSchema.DEFAULT_ARRAY_ELEMENT_SEPARATOR)
            .withNullValue(StringUtils.EMPTY)
            .withoutEscapeChar();
    return mapper
            .readerFor(clazz)
            .with(CsvParser.Feature.TRIM_SPACES)
            .with(CsvParser.Feature.SKIP_EMPTY_LINES)
            .with(schema)
            .<T>readValues(stream)
            .readAll();
}

// your csv line represents this DTO class
class YourDtoClass {
    private String name;
    private String surname;
    // ...
}
```

And if you need to persist csv file into database, you could [convert InputStream into byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java) and [persist it to database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32572422/store-byte-array-in-mysql-with-hibernate).

Actually, `InputStream` can't be processed twice, but there are some workarounds, and one of them - store `InputStream` into a temporary file, and after that, you could read data from temp file multiple times.

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile(prefix, suffix);
FileUtils.copyInputStreamToFile(inputStream, tempFile); // from `org.apache.commons.io`
```

and after operating on temp file, make sure that you remove it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If use an InputStream to parse the file, I will need another InputStream to get bytes to store the file right? Is it better to use getBytes() method of the MultipartFile to not have 2 objects in that case to parse an to store the file? Also, it means that the file is stored in memory (RAM) no?

Comment: I posted update into my answer. Indeed, you can't process `InputStream` multiple times, but for that you could use temp file